# How rSAP (Remote SIM Acces Profile) on Android via BLuetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I need to develop an application which can read the phonebook of another device via bluetooth.
Usually both server and client parts should be  developed but i think in my case it is possible to skip the server side.
In my car when i pair my  MultimediaCar System with my Phone all phonebook is transfered into the car memory, so i suppose it is possible to do the same with my application.

Does someone know how I can do that?